# WP7 Using binding how can I manage data relevant on prior items

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

When I am binding to a collection with a listbox, is there any way I can  manage the output based upon the prior items that were displayed in the collection.

For example in the following binding

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="AgendaListbox"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AgendaItems2}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventDisplay3}"/>
</Grid>
```

Where the Template is as follows

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EventDisplay3">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTimeDayString}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayTimeString}" Foreground="{Binding DisplayColor}"
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
                   Grid.Row="0" FontSize="30" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If I want to alter the display based upon they previous item that was displayed (e.g say I want to drop the DateTimeString Binding if its identical to the previous one) is there a way that I can do it without having to make specific allowance for it when I build up the collecton.

Because so much happens automatically as it were with the listbox being bound to that collection I cannot see any other way without me handling this as  the collection is being built... because after that I have little control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can manage the output based upon the prior items that were displayed in the collection?

**No.**

You have to do such changes when you build the collection. Consider if using a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) can be of any help.

Comment: Great - thanks.  I will look at the DataTemplateSelector and see if I can make use of it.